# Two Pair - what beats what

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules, reading-hands

In two pair - would a Queen Seven two pair, beat a queen three, two pair on the board.

Is it both cards that count or, or just the highest card?

I suppose the lowest card would not count in a two pair when there is a definite higher card beating the queen example above for instance (and ace or king high card two pair).

Thanks

Comment: Is it queens and sevens on the board or Queens and threes on the board, it needs to be one or the other please be clear. Click on the reading hands tag, you will find the answer to your question, kind of a teaching you to fish thing.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean the community cards were something like K♥K♠4♥4⋄J♣

with player 1 having say Q⋄7♥ and player 2 Q♣3♣

then its a split pot, winning hands being KK44Q.

Comment: replace that jack on the board with a seven, then the player has a better two pair, queens and sevens.

Comment: OP didn't ask that

Comment: not sure what he asked;)

Answer (score 0):

When I read your question, I thought you were saying "the board is showing QQ33x and a particular player is holding 77 in the pocket." If that interpretation is correct, then yes, the queens and sevens two pair would beat the queens and threes two pair. When multiple players have two pair and the higher pair is the same, the lower pair is used as the tiebreaker.

If I didn't understand your question correctly — like Jon, I'm not absolutely sure what you asked — then Jon Mark Perry's answer could also be correct.